# Pandas Dataframe Replace Substring

Tags: pandas, dataframe, replace, substring

For instance I have data similar to this

```
      name                    flag               seen_week_end
0    Mick Am Johnson         TRUE                 03/05/2017
1    Brian Ma Yeager          FALSE                 NaN
2    Maggie Alvarez       FALSE                NaN
3    Christine Ma Yin           FALSE                NaN
```

In the above dataframe I want to replace the word in name column

```
Am as Yan
Ma as Mu
```

How to use dictionary and replace?

Answer (score 2):

Here is `replace`

```
df['name']=df['name'].replace({r'\bAm\b':'Yan',r'\bMa\b':'Mu'},regex=True)
```